# Change colors in multiple annotations

Tags: r, pheatmap

I want to change the colors of multiple annotations of my heatmap. Example code:

```
#test data
test = matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10)
test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] = test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] + 3
test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 2
test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 4
colnames(test) = paste("Test", 1:10, sep = "")
rownames(test) = paste("Gene", 1:20, sep = "")
#plot
annotation <- data.frame(Var1 = factor(1:10 %% 2 == 0, labels = c("Exp1", "None")), Var1 = factor(1:10 %% 2 == 0, labels = c("Exp1", "None")))
rownames(annotation) <- colnames(test) # check out the row names of annotation
pheatmap(test, annotation = annotation)
```

[image]

Expected outcome is white color in the `None` category and black color in `Exp1` and `Exp2` category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify `annotation_colors`:

```
# Specify colors
annotation_colors = list(
  Var1 = c(Exp1="black", None="white"),
  Var1.1 = c(Exp1="black", None="white"))
pheatmap(test, annotation = annotation, annotation_colors = annotation_colors)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!